# What's the point of using "./" in a path?

Tags: terminal, path, directory, webpack, root

I'm learning webpack from [this site](http://webpack.github.io/docs/tutorials/getting-started/) and notice they tell me to use webpack ./entry.js bundle.js in the terminal but it still works even if I use webpack entry.js bundle.js as long as I'm in the root directory. I think I know that "./" signifies that the file is in the current directory, but it works the same without it, so what's the point? Is it just more clear?

Comment: In short, there is no difference between the two so you are right in your assumption. This link doesn't touch your question but does contain information about pathing in general: [Web File Paths](https://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/)

Comment: @lovermanthing so ./ and ../ are the same thing?

Comment: No.. `./` is your current directory and `../` is to go up one folder. You can use something such as `../../` to go up two directories or use the slash `/` by itself to go ALL the way to your ROOT directory. That help? (sorry for the slow response)

Comment: Here's a coding example with instructions that might help you see how they work. [Pathing Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lovermanthing/fp3aoxf5/)